# Fedora 15 force gnome fallback mode

Tags: gnome, fedora

Ok, so my Fedora 15 starts with gnome-shell. Which works until it decides not to, and the screan starts tearing. It's documented [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Gnome3) how to force fallback to the old gnome-panel , i.e. go to System-Settings->System info. Problem is starting System Info tears my screen, and virtually everyting turns white.

So, is there any config file, gconf setting or other I can edit to force the fallback mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue the command:

```
   dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session session-name 'gnome-fallback'
```

According to this page:

http://fedorasolved.org/Members/bookwar/gnome-3-tips